# Working with file using Groovy

Tags: java, file, groovy, jar

I want to perform some operation on a jar file like Adding folders/files and removing them.

I can do that using Java. But I would like to achieve it using Groovy.

But no idea about methods or classes. I am newbie to Groovy and willing to learn and enjoy it's features .

Can someone provide me a very basic groovy script to add folder/file OR if possible simply provide me some links to work with jar file.

That would be helpful !!

Comment: Groovy runs on JVM, so you can use java classes in groovy as well.

Comment: http://groovy.codehaus.org/Recipes+For+File

Comment: @Adi read my question carefully before answering

Comment: @Fincio thnx 4 d link

Comment: groovy doesn't provide such functionality out of the box, it would simplify your code

Comment: @injecteer I am looking for those methods only which will simplify my work.

Comment: If you have something that works in Java, just use it in Groovy and call it a day. Don't overcomplicate the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a Groovy script which demonstrates use of AntBuilder to update a jar file. You provide it two arguments, the jar file and the file you want to add to the jar.

```
def (jar, include) = [new File(args[0]), new File(args[1])].each { f -> 
    if (!f.exists()) {
        println "$f does not exist"
        System.exit(0);
    }
    f
}

def ant = new AntBuilder()
if (include.isDirectory()) {
    println "Adding contents of $include to $jar"
    ant.jar(update:true, destfile: jar.absolutePath) {
        fileset(dir: include.absolutePath)
    }
} else {
    println "Adding file $include to $jar"
    ant.jar(update:true, destfile: jar.absolutePath, includesfile: include.absolutePath)
}
```

You could also use the classes in the [`java.util.jar` package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/jar/package-summary.html) to work with jar files.

AntBuilder is essentially a wrapper over Ant that allows you to compose tasks using Groovy syntax. Refer to the [Ant manual](http://ant.apache.org/manual/) for available tasks and the Groovy [AntBuilder documentation](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Using+Ant+from+Groovy) for the Groovy syntax.

Comment: Can u refer me smthng to know more about AntBuilder ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example creating a folder + file:

```
def ant = new AntBuilder()
ant.mkdir( dir: 'C:\Folder\' )
def file = new File( 'C:\Folder\', 'TestFile'+ '.txt').newWriter()
file.writeLine( 'File content' )
file.close
```

Comment: i want to work on .jar file